# how to add a dollar sign through css content

Tags: css, css-content

How can I display the "$" sign through CSS Content:" " I've tried all kinds of different codes. Putting just

```
div.example {Content:"$1000";}
```

displays on the site like "00".

Trying to do this before resorting to Javascript.

Comment: Please show any applicable HTML as well.

Answer (score 17):

```
.dollar:before {
    content: '$';
}
```

Comment: Modern usage is `::`.  From MDN, *CSS3 introduced the `::before` notation (with two colons) to distinguish **pseudo-classes** from **pseudo-elements**.* --  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for displaying the dollar sign in the CSS content property

```
div.example { content: "\0024"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough HTML to go on, but to take a shot:

The CSS property `content` is to be used with `::before` and `::after`and when i put a $ inside my content declaration, everything works...

[See JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w3t5o2ee/)