# Change all prices on the page from one currency to another with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't need to use Yahoo Finance api or such. Simply multiply the numbers by a fixed amount.

[See codepen](https://codepen.io/simii/pen/MEpRWd). Dropdown functionality is not implemented, I want to have the exchange down first.
I know this is just the start, but how to go on? This obviously needs several problems to be solved:

- This currently changes every value to the same
- I need the ability to change them back when selecting the USD again
- Is it too inefficient to not give classnames, but find all the prices (contains $ or €) automatically?

Could you give me some pointers how should I go on, please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//  $('select').material_select();
  $('.caret').text(" ");
  //here starts my attempt for the exchange
  var price = $(".price").text().replace("$", "");
  var convertedToNumber = parseFloat(price);
  var eurPrice = convertedToNumber / 1.18;
  $(".price").text(eurPrice);


});
```

```css
input.select-dropdown {
  color: #26a69a;
}
.caret {
  background:url("http://svgshare.com/i/3Bc.svg") no-repeat 90% 50%;
  width:20px;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="input-field col s1">
    <select>
          <option value="1" selected>USD</option>
          <option value="2">EUR</option>
        </select>
    <label>Currency</label>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="currencies">
  <li class="price">$1500</li>
  <li class="price">$2000</li>
  <li class="price">$342</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For the dollar sign you can use CSS classes. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997297/how-to-add-a-dollar-sign-through-css-content

Comment: You really should take a look at "data binding" in web applications. It will make this flow easier. There are lot of libraries that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would have to update the prices whenever the exchange rate changed, you can have two sets

**Data attributes**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#curr").on("change",function() {
    var curr   = this.value;
    var prefix = curr=="usd"; // or ["usd","yen",...].indexOf(curr); for more
    var sign   = curr=="usd"?"$":"€";
    $(".price").each(function(){
      $(this).text(
        (prefix?sign:"")   +
        $(this).data(curr) +
        (prefix?"":sign)
      );  
    })
  }).change();
});
```

```css
input.select-dropdown {
  color: #26a69a;
}
.caret {
  background:url("http://svgshare.com/i/3Bc.svg") no-repeat 90% 50%;
  width:20px;
  height:auto;
}
.currencies { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="input-field col s1">
    <select id="curr">
          <option value="usd" selected>USD</option>
          <option value="eur">EUR</option>
        </select>
    <label>Currency</label>
  </div>
</div>


<br />Price 1
  <span class="price" data-usd="1,500" data-eur="1.271">$1,500</span>

<br />Price 2

<span class="price" data-usd="2,000" data-eur="1.702">$2,000</span>

<br />Price 3

<span class="price" data-usd="342" data-eur="291">$342</span>
```

**Show and hide:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#curr").on("change",function() {
    $(".currencies").hide();
    $("."+this.value).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```css
input.select-dropdown {
  color: #26a69a;
}
.caret {
  background:url("http://svgshare.com/i/3Bc.svg") no-repeat 90% 50%;
  width:20px;
  height:auto;
}
.currencies { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="input-field col s1">
    <select id="curr">
          <option value="usd" selected>USD</option>
          <option value="eur">EUR</option>
        </select>
    <label>Currency</label>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="currencies usd">
  <li class="price">$1,500</li>
  <li class="price">$2,000</li>
  <li class="price">$342</li>
</ul>
<ul class="currencies eur">
  <li class="price">1.276€</li>
  <li class="price">1.702€</li>
  <li class="price">291€</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this seems like a reasonably simple solution. I have a question though, the euro sign should go after the price, not before like the dollar... I've been tinkering for a while now, but can't make it happen with your code! Could you help me out, please?

Comment: Please see update - As a Euro user I actually prefer EUR1.200 instead of 1.200€

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called data binding and there are a lot of libraries and stuff that will provide it for you.

I will assume you have no idea what I'm talking about and I'll just explain to you what the basic idea is.

You have a set of data, in your case prices.

```
var prices = [
  1500,
  2000,
  342
];
```

Then you have your object of currency rates

```
var rates = {
  USD: 1, // obviously
  EUR: 0.86
}
```

Now every time the currency is changed you recalculate the price and update every occurrence.

```
function updatePrices(rate) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("price");

  prices.forEach((price, index) => {
    elements[index].innerHTML = price * rate
  });
}

document.getElementById("selector").onchange = function() {
  updatePrices(rates[this.value]);
}
```

And call it initially as well.

```
updatePrices(rates.USD);
```

Now obviously this is a very dumb way to bind your data, using array indexes and class names, but that's the basic idea behind it.

As to the currency signs, it is generally a bad idea to include them as very few currencies actually have them but the idea is the same.

```js
var prices = [
  1500,
  2000,
  342
];


var rates = {
  USD: 1, // obviously
  EUR: 0.86
}

function updatePrices(rate) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("price");

  prices.forEach((price, index) => {
    elements[index].innerHTML = price * rate
  });
}

document.getElementById("selector").onchange = function() {
  updatePrices(rates[this.value]);
}


updatePrices(rates.USD);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s1">
    <select id="selector">
          <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
    <label>Currency</label>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="currencies">
  <li class="price"></li>
  <li class="price"></li>
  <li class="price"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You miss the currency code but is the more elegant for many prices on the page

Comment: @mplungjan as I said the idea is the same, nothing is stopping you from adding it.

Comment: This is nice because this is all vanilla - no jquery :) Question though? What if the data needs to be inputed inlined? Like in cms content wise?

Comment: @Riskbreaker it doesn't matter where your data is coming from or I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of switching the sign using jquery - you can use CSS class
   (Based on: [how to add a dollar sign through css content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997297/how-to-add-a-dollar-sign-through-css-content))

   ```
   ul.dollar li:before {
     content: "\0024";
   }
   ul.euro li:before {
     content: "\20ac";
   }
   ```
2. For changing the value in each one you should use `each`

   ```
     $.each($(".price"), function(i, p) {
       var convertedToNumber = parseFloat($(p).text());
       var eurPrice = convertedToNumber / 1.18;
       $(p).text(eurPrice);
     });
   ```

See running example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGZrpX

Comment: Your pen does not revert